# Extract Twitter Handles instead of Screen Names using twitteR package?

Tags: r, twitter

I am using the twitteR package and I want to get the twitter handles of my followers instead of the Screen Name, example if a hypothetical user John Biden was one of my followers as his Screen Name but handle as @JohnB80, I want to extract the @JohnB80. Currently I can get the twitter ID and the Screen Name but not the handle. Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

This (dummy) code should do the trick:

```
meUser <- getUser("myHandle")
followerHandleList <- meUser$getFollowers()
```

This will return a list of Twitter handles (without @'s).

Comment: Thanks Spencer  for the input but it actually gives the Name displayed rather than the handle, have now figured out a solution

Comment: @AnuragH This is very odd. When I run the code using my own Twitter handle for "myHandle", I get a list of the Twitter handles (again, without the @) for my followers. Here's a snippet of my output
`$41120559
[1] "MORMONorg"

$281402189
[1] "3dgamelab"`

Not sure why the same isn't working for you :-/

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution so what we have to do is:

```
user <- getUser("XXXXX")    #Enter the user Screen Name
followers<-user$getFollowerIDs()   #Get the Followers UserIDs
names=lookupUsers(followers)       #Get the detailed list about followers
usernames=data.frame(sapply(names, `[[`,"screenName"))  #Extract Screen Name
```